# tsc don't create a bunch of .js files in my project. Put them in dist

Tags: typescript, tsc

I want tsc to compile all the .ts files to .js files, then put them somewhere else.

My tsconfig has the option `"outDir": "./dist",`.

I ran a command targeted at my core file `tsc ./src/server.ts`.

How do I make tsc not create a bunch of js files all over the place and put them in the dist instead?

EDIT: I figured out what I was doing wrong.  Is there any way to tell typescript (perhaps on a global scale) to never, ever, ever make a bunch of in place js files?  It's a real hassle to accidentally do that then have to clean it up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't direct tsc to any file.

Just run `tsc` without the `./src/server.ts`

As far as I can tell, there is no way to globally disable tsc from shooting out .js files everywhere if you happen to mess up the command.  The safest bet is to create a script in `package.json` and only ever call that.

If you need to quickly delete a bunch of js files, you can do so like this (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/116390/132794):

**MAKE SURE TO HAVE THE RIGHT DIRECTORY**

```
find /path/to/directory -type f -name '*.js' -exec rm {} +
```

If you keep your src in root level directory next to node_modules, you'll have to do some extra to not delete your modules.  Or just delete the whole node_modules folder, then run `npm i` again.  If anything breaks, you were going to have to fix that anyways.

Answer (score 4):

Setting `"noEmit": true` under `compilerOptions` in `tsconfig.json` will result in `.js` files not being created.

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noEmit": true,
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `tsconfig.json` you need to ensure `"sourceMap": true`, this will ensure the sibling .js files aren't created during a tsc build